# Delete all elements that do not possess specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small document in which each tag have an attribute like

`keep="true"`

How can I iterate through the whole `<body></body>` and remove the whole innerHTML of these tags (removing them itself as well) that do not have this attribute set.

I would prefer to use jQuery, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine a [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector with an [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$(":not([keep='true'])").remove();
```

Or maybe even a simple [Has Attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector, depending on your markup semantics:

```
$(":not([keep])").remove();
```

*Edit:* If you want to remove the matched elements but keep their contents, you can chain [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) into [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) instead:

```
$(":not([keep])").children().unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Is it possible for me to set `keep="true"` for e.g. a `<div>` and have it's childrens skipped (kept along with the parent)?

Comment: @user, yes, you would have to use `children().unwrap()` instead of `remove()` to do that.

Comment: I meant - is it possible to keep childrens if their parent have the attribute set, even if the meant childrens do not have it?

Comment: @user, that depends. Are your `[keep]` elements all same-level siblings under a common ancestor? (You really should have mentioned these requirements in your question, though.)

Comment: it all differs with almost each div. Some have simple text content, others include multi-level structures... It would be perfect to keep all parents with Attribute, all their childrens and childrens of their childrens etc.

Answer (score 1):

`keep` is not a valid attribute, you can use `data-*` attribute and try:

```
$('*:not([data-keep="true"])').empty()
```

---

```
$('div:not([data-keep="true"])').empty()
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to set data-keep="true" for e.g. a <div> and have it's childrens skipped (kept along with the parent)?

Comment: yes, you can select div tags which is also faster than using universal selector, try the updated answer.

Comment: I meant - is it possible to keep childrens if their parent have the attribute set, even if the meant childrens do not have it?

Comment: @user1559555 yes, I understood, the updated answer keeps the children of the div tags that have `data-keep="true"` attributes and remove children of those that don't have.